# PR2: Running a Realtime joint controller problem

Tags: gazebo, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello...

i'm trying to realize the "Runing a Realtime joint controller" tutorial, i did everything how the tutorial said, i think that my probnlem is with the controller name, but in another question @lorenz tells me that isn't my problem...

what i do was the following:

i opened the gazebo with the PR2 and open the rxconsole, later i wrote:

```
$ rosparam set my_controller_name/type MyControllerPlugin
$ rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager list-joints

Waiting for mechanism statistics message...
Actuators:
    0 bl_caster_l_wheel_motor
    1 bl_caster_r_wheel_motor
    2 bl_caster_rotation_motor
    3 br_caster_l_wheel_motor
    4 br_caster_r_wheel_motor
    5 br_caster_rotation_motor
    6 fl_caster_l_wheel_motor
    7 fl_caster_r_wheel_motor
    8 fl_caster_rotation_motor
    9 fr_caster_l_wheel_motor
   10 fr_caster_r_wheel_motor
   11 fr_caster_rotation_motor
   12 head_pan_motor
   13 head_tilt_motor
   14 l_elbow_flex_motor
   15 l_forearm_roll_motor
   16 l_gripper_motor
   17 l_shoulder_lift_motor
   18 l_shoulder_pan_motor
   19 l_upper_arm_roll_motor
   20 l_wrist_l_motor
   21 l_wrist_r_motor
   22 laser_tilt_mount_motor
   23 r_elbow_flex_motor
   24 r_forearm_roll_motor
   25 r_gripper_motor
   26 r_shoulder_lift_motor
   27 r_shoulder_pan_motor
   28 r_upper_arm_roll_motor
   29 r_wrist_l_motor
   30 r_wrist_r_motor
   31 torso_lift_motor
Joints:
    0 fl_caster_rotation_joint
    1 fl_caster_l_wheel_joint
    2 fl_caster_r_wheel_joint
    3 fr_caster_rotation_joint
    4 fr_caster_l_wheel_joint
    5 fr_caster_r_wheel_joint
    6 bl_caster_rotation_joint
    7 bl_caster_l_wheel_joint
    8 bl_caster_r_wheel_joint
    9 br_caster_rotation_joint
   10 br_caster_l_wheel_joint
   11 br_caster_r_wheel_joint
   12 torso_lift_joint
   13 torso_lift_motor_screw_joint
   14 head_pan_joint
   15 head_tilt_joint
   16 laser_tilt_mount_joint
   17 r_upper_arm_roll_joint
   18 r_shoulder_pan_joint
   19 r_shoulder_lift_joint
   20 r_forearm_roll_joint
   21 r_elbow_flex_joint
   22 r_wrist_flex_joint
   23 r_wrist_roll_joint
   24 r_gripper_joint
   25 r_gripper_l_finger_joint
   26 r_gripper_r_finger_joint
   27 r_gripper_r_finger_tip_joint
   28 r_gripper_l_finger_tip_joint
   29 r_gripper_motor_screw_joint
   30 r_gripper_motor_slider_joint
   31 l_upper_arm_roll_joint
   32 l_shoulder_pan_joint
   33 l_shoulder_lift_joint
   34 l_forearm_roll_joint
   35 l_elbow_flex_joint
   36 l_wrist_flex_joint
   37 l_wrist_roll_joint
   38 l_gripper_joint
   39 l_gripper_l_finger_joint
   40 l_gripper_r_finger_joint
   41 l_gripper_r_finger_tip_joint
   42 l_gripper_l_finger_tip_joint
   43 l_gripper_motor_screw_joint
   44 l_gripper_motor_slider_joint

$ rosparam set my_controller_name/joint_name r_shoulder_pan_joint
$ rosparam get -p my_controller_name
```

and i obtain :

```
joint_name: r_shoulder_pan_joint
type: MyControllerPlugin

$ rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager list

base_controller ( running )
base_odometry ( running )
head_traj_controller ( running )
l_arm_controller ( running )
l_gripper_controller ( running )
laser_tilt_controller ( running )
r_arm_controller ( running )
r_gripper_controller ( running )
torso_controller ( running )
```

in this case i don't stop any controller (i have to?)

```
$rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager list-types


JointGravityController
JointPendulumController
ethercat_trigger_controllers/MultiTriggerController
ethercat_trigger_controllers/ProjectorController
ethercat_trigger_controllers/TriggerController
pr2_calibration_controllers/CasterCalibrationController
pr2_calibration_controllers/FakeCalibrationController
pr2_calibration_controllers/GripperCalibrationController
pr2_calibration_controllers/JointCalibrationController
pr2_calibration_controllers/WristCalibrationController
pr2_controller_manager/TestController
pr2_mechanism_controllers/CasterController
pr2_mechanism_controllers/CasterControllerNode
pr2_mechanism_controllers/LaserScannerTrajController
pr2_mechanism_controllers/Pr2BaseController
pr2_mechanism_controllers/Pr2BaseController2
pr2_mechanism_controllers/Pr2GripperController
pr2_mechanism_controllers/Pr2Odometry
robot_mechanism_controllers/CartesianPoseController
robot_mechanism_controllers/CartesianTwistController
robot_mechanism_controllers/CartesianWrenchController
robot_mechanism_controllers/JTCartesianController
robot_mechanism_controllers/JointEffortController
robot_mechanism_controllers/JointPositionController
robot_mechanism_controllers/JointSplineTrajectoryController
robot_mechanism_controllers/JointTrajectoryActionController
robot_mechanism_controllers/JointVelocityController

$rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager load my_controller_name
```

and i obtain the first error:

```
Error when loading my_controller_name
```

if i continue i obtain the following lines:

```
$rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager list

base_controller ( running )
base_odometry ( running )
head_traj_controller ( running )
l_arm_controller ( running )
l_gripper_controller ( running )
laser_tilt_controller ( running )
r_arm_controller ( running )
r_gripper_controller ( running )
torso_controller ( running )
```

i try to:

```
$rosparam set my_controller_name/type my_controller_pkg/MyControllerPlugin
```

but the problem persist.

If anyone could help me i gonna thank you....

the output of

```
rospack plugins --attrib=plugin pr2_controller_interface


pr2_controller_manager /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/test/controller_plugin.xml
pr2_gazebo_benchmarks /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/pr2_simulator/pr2_gazebo_benchmarks/gazebo_physics_controller_plugins.xml
pr2_mechanism_controllers /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/pr2_controllers/pr2_mechanism_controllers/controller_plugins.xml
my_controller_pkg /home/jose/ros_pkg_tutorials/my_controller_pkg/controller_plugins.xml
ethercat_trigger_controllers /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/pr2_controllers/ethercat_trigger_controllers/controller_plugins.xml
pr2_calibration_controllers /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/pr2_controllers/pr2_calibration_controllers/controller_plugins.xml
robot_mechanism_controllers /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/pr2_controllers/robot_mechanism_controllers/controller_plugins.xml
```

this is the contents of the controller_plugin.xml:

```
<library path="lib/libmy_controller_lib">
  <class name="my_controller_pkg/MyControllerPlugin" 
         type="my_controller_ns::MyControllerClass"           
         base_class_type="pr2_controller_interface::Controller" />
</library>
```

well here is something wrong:

```
jose@ubuntu:~$ rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager list-types
JointGravityController
JointPendulumController
ethercat_trigger_controllers/MultiTriggerController
ethercat_trigger_controllers/ProjectorController
ethercat_trigger_controllers/TriggerController
pr2_calibration_controllers/CasterCalibrationController
pr2_calibration_controllers/FakeCalibrationController
pr2_calibration_controllers/GripperCalibrationController
pr2_calibration_controllers/JointCalibrationController
pr2_calibration_controllers/WristCalibrationController
pr2_controller_manager/TestController
pr2_mechanism_controllers/CasterController
pr2_mechanism_controllers/CasterControllerNode
pr2_mechanism_controllers/LaserScannerTrajController
pr2_mechanism_controllers/Pr2BaseController
pr2_mechanism_controllers/Pr2BaseController2
pr2_mechanism_controllers/Pr2GripperController
pr2_mechanism_controllers/Pr2Odometry
robot_mechanism_controllers/CartesianPoseController
robot_mechanism_controllers/CartesianTwistController
robot_mechanism_controllers/CartesianWrenchController
robot_mechanism_controllers/JTCartesianController
robot_mechanism_controllers/JointEffortController
robot_mechanism_controllers/JointPositionController
robot_mechanism_controllers/JointSplineTrajectoryController
robot_mechanism_controllers/JointTrajectoryActionController
robot_mechanism_controllers/JointVelocityController
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47561/pr2:-running-a-realtime-joint-controller-problem/) by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you can see, the controller named `MyControllerPlugin` is not known in your system. Did you really follow the previous tutorial as it is assumed (stated at the beginning of the tutorial page you are referring to)? You can find it [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller). It shows you how to actually write the controller and declare the plugin properly.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-06**:
yes Lorenz, i do everithing, i'll do the tutorials again...

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-06**:
I still believe that something is wrong with your ros package defining the controller. Is it in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH? Please **edit** your question and add the output of `rospack plugins --attrib=plugin pr2_controller_interface` executed in your controller package.

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-06**:
i export the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to my home, there is where i created the directory... in this moments i'm making the previous tutorial again

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-06**:
Well, i don't have succes with it, i did all the previous tutorial an the runing one to, but it has the same problem.... when i create the plugin description file where i have to save it?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-06**:
Sorry, I cannot help if you do not provide the information I ask for. What's the output of the `rospack plugins` command as shown at the bottom of the tutorial and in my previous comment? Please **edit** your question to add information. Just saying 'it doesn't work' just costs time...

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-06**:
Thanks. So the controller_plugins.xml file of my_controller_pkg is known at least. Can you add the contents of that file to your question please? Please format the code correctly (mark it and press Ctrl-k).

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-06**:
Ok. That looks good, too. Are you using gazebo? Did you actually restart it? Otherwise, the list of controller plugins might be outdated.

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-06**:
i closed the gazebo and run it again, the problem persist

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-06**:
Double-check with `rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager list-types`. If `my_controller_pkg/MyControllerPlugin` should be in the list. If it is, try setting the controller type to `my_controller_pkg/MyControllerPlugin` instead of `MyControllerPlugin` in the ros parameter.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-06**:
I still think there is something wrong with your package path settings or something like that. In the terminal you are launching gazebo from, can you roscd into my_controller_pkg? I'm running out of ideas slowly :)

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-06**:
when i use roscd into the my_controller_pkg, it don't works, i gonna try exporting the ROS PACKAGE PATH... no, exporting the path persist the problem... like you, i don't have idea what is

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-06**:
So if you cannot roscd into your controller package in the terminal you run gazebo from, that is the problem. I suggest that you clean up your configuration and try again. E.g. follow http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays Then close all terminals and try everything again.

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-06**:
the roscd works, i only have to export the ros package path to my controller pkg directory...

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-06**:
well.... after a entire day trying and trying that, the mistake disapear, i export the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in every terminal i have open.. export and open gazebo, export and charge the PR2, export and open rxconsole and export in the window that i was working, and everything was OK... Thank you!!!

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-06**:
As I said, the problem probably was just the way you set ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. I really suggest you set up a clean overlay as shown at http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays. It will help avoiding such problems and will save you a lot of time in the future.